# Максимально количество узлов в дереве Хаффмана

Tags: алгоритм

Какое максимальное количество узлов в дереве Хаффмана если мощность алфавита 256 символов?

Comment: Ну, как мне кажется, это будет в случае вырожденного дерева. 256 листьев + 255 внутренних узлов, так что если считать листья узлами — 511.

Comment: Дерево Хаффмана - двоичное дерево у которог каждый внутренний узел имеет двух потомков. По индукции доказывается что число внутренних узлов на один меньше числа листьев. См. комментарий @Harry далее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, как-то не сложилось в голове, что глубина и число узлов — вещи перпендикулярные. Так что ответ дал верный, но неверный... :)